# Disable spark tab bar tabs

Tags: user-interface, apache-flex, tabs, flex4, flex-spark

I have been able to disable tabs in a tab bar using the following helpful tutorial.

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/25/enabling-and-disabling-specific-tabs-in-a-tabbar-control/

This only works for mx tabbar. Does anyone know how to do this for a spark tabbar? I prefer the lnf of the spark one. When I try it with a spark tab bar it just disables the viewstack of the tab and not the actual tab.

An alternative solution may just be to make the mx tab bar look like a spark toolbar with the rounded edges. Any ideas on this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this post in the Adobe Forums, [How to Disable a tab in a spark tab bar](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/650960), your best solution seems to be a custom skin. There is also a 'hack' mentioned at the end, that was posted last month.

Give the control you have with the new structure I think the custom skin makes the most sense.